# ExtJS - disable Quick Tip on Ext.window.Window close button

Tags: extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have a view that extends Ext.window.Window:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.help.Module', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',

    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this,
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Ext.QuickTips.init() is run when the application first starts up. Later on, when I create an instance of MyApp.view.help.Module as follows:

```
var module = Ext.create('MyApp.view.help.Module');
module.show()
```

A quick tip "Close Dialog" is shown over the 'X' button in the window. How can I disable the quicktip?

I know I can run Ext.QuickTip.disable(), however that disables the quick tips globally when I just want the quick tip over the 'X' button to be disabled.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just define the closeToolText property as an empty string as Kevin Lee said or null as follows:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.help.Module', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    closeToolText: null,

    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this,
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define the closeToolText property as an empty string as follows:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.help.Module', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    closeToolText: '',

    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this,
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```